# Unexpected global variable values; skewheap implementation in c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, struct, heap

I am trying to implement the skewheap for my data structures lectures. Ignoring whether the algotihm works, I have a problem with code itself. On VS 2012 code runs but returns unexpected results. During debugging the value of a global variable (`root`) changes unexpectedly. Before entering to `Insert(1)` function (line 72) the values of `root` are what I expected them to be (`key=5`, `right=NULL`, `left=NULL`). However when stepping inside the `Insert()`, `root` value fields changes randomly. Next, when reaching line 45:

```
node *p = &input;
```

`root` changes values to (`input->key`, `null`, `null`). In Dev C++ the program is shut down with a `SIGSEV`. In general sistuation look similar, but in `Print()`, pointers to `left` and `right` changes value to some unexpected values. What are the reasons for this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

struct node
{
    int key;
    node* right;
    node* left;
    node(int _key, node* _right, node* _left)
    {
        key = _key;
        right = _right;
        left = _left;
    }
};

node* root = NULL;

node* Union(node* p1, node* p2)
{
    node* p;
    if (!p1)
        return p2;
    if (!p2)
        return p1;
    if (p1->key > p2->key) {
        p = p1;
        Union(p1->right, p2);
    } else {
        p = p2;
        Union(p1, p2->right);
    }

    swap(p->left, p->right);
    return p;
}


void Insert(int v)
{
    node input = node(v, NULL, NULL);
    node* p = &input;
    root = Union(root, p);
}

void Print(node* v)
{
    if (!v) {
        return;
    }

    if (v->right) {
        Print(v->right);
    }

    cout << v->key << endl;

    if (v->left) {
        Print(v->left);
    }
}

int main()
{
    Insert(5);
    Insert(1);
    cout << root->key;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`input` is local to the scope of `Insert()` because it is declared as an automatic variable inside the body. It doesn't have dynamic storage-duration like an object declared with `new` does. If your `Union()` method returns `p2` (that is, if it returns a node from `input`), then `root` will still be pointing to an object that still be destroyed when the `Insert()` function ends. This is called a *dangling pointer*.

Declare your object dynamically to prevent this from happening:

```
node* input = new node(v, NULL, NULL);
node* p = input;
root = Union(root, p);
```

Comment: I'd like to point out that none of the nodes are freed in this program, so it is leaking memory unless that's taken care of. It may be a good idea to use unique_ptr or shared_ptr around the nodes, unless you take care to delete them manually. The risk of leaks is high, and might outweigh the small overhead of a smart pointer.